# How do I unhide a row of a table using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, hide

I have a table element with inside the tbody and several tr elements.
One of the tr elements (rows) is hidden by default using display:none, I do not use the visibility:hidden function since the space left behind is not collapsed this way. So far it works, now the thing I would like to have is to let the row reappear conditioned on an action such as :hover or :active using CSS. When I change the display condition of the row based on such an action the row does expand, however, it only shows white space. When I change the width of the (td div div) inside the tr element, the cells of the row do reappear since the width of these cells are equal to zero after using display:none. I can't seem to change the width of the cells conditioned on an action using CSS (I can change the background-color of this element for example). So my question is, how can I work past this? I can only use HTML or CSS.

Comment: Do you have any code samples or maybe post one on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The `:hover` or `:active` are not actions, but states, or to be exact `pseudo-classes`. And since you made the element not show via `display:none`, they cannot be hovered (you cannot hover something that is not there) or activated (unless you activate it via JS or the like).

What you can toy around with, is making children visible via hovering the parent. But it is considered a rather dirty solution, and is unlikely to achieve the desired effect, since it does not change the DOM what I guess you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I think I have not stated my problem clearly enough. I mean that I want to click another row which actually is visible. That is, I want to hover row 2, which is visible, to unhide row 3 which was by default not visible. I have accessed row using: .... tr:nth-child(2):active~tr:nth-child(3).

Comment: Ah, yes, in this case it's possible of course. It would be great if you add some code with the next question you have though, so it will be clearer what the problem exactly is and people can help you more efficiently. :)

Comment: Here is a JSfiddle. It works here, however, within the environment which I use it, the width of the div with the class: "comp cx-simple_value" jumps to zero. I can't adjust the width of these div's using the same code which I use to unhide the row. I hope it's clear from this.

http://jsfiddle.net/on2hLsuw/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't show the `tr` based on `div:hover`.

You have to do this via JavaScript

### If you use `jQuery`

```
var mytr = $("#mytr");
$("#mydiv").hover(function() {
    mytr.css("display", "initial")
});
```

### If you don't

You can't put a `onhover` listener in vanilla JavaScript. You can, however, use `onmouseenter` to show the element, and on `onmouseleave` to hide it again

```
var mytr = document.getElementById("mytr");
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");

mydiv.onmouseenter = function() {
    mytr.style.display = "initial";
}

mydiv.onmouseleave = function() {
    mytr.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: This basically applies for anything, not just `tr` and `div`, you can use these methods to hide/unhide unrelated stuff